# Old domain controller still showing up in ADSS

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

Yesterday I demoted a domain controller, removed it from the domain and shut it down.  My new Primary Domain Controller is up and running just fine (along with a secondary).  Replication status is normal and doesn't show the old DC.

However, when I go into Active Directory Sites and Services -> SITE NAME -> Servers I still see the old DC.  If I expand it there is nothing (unlike the other DC's which have `NTDS Settings`).

Is it ok to delete this server?  It doesn't show up in the DOMAIN CONTROLLER organizational unit under Active Directory Users and Computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete it right in ADS&S. See this article about manually removing domain controllers:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/02/17/step-by-step-removing-a-domain-controller-server-manually/

The relevant section:

> **Step 2: Cleaning up the DC server instance from the Active Directory Sites and Services**
>
> 1. Go to Server manager > Tools > Active Directory Sites and Services
> 2. Expand the Sites and go to the server which need to remove
> 3. Right click and click Delete
> 4. In next window click yes to confirm

You might want to do this too, just in case:

> **Step 3: Clean up metadata using ntdsutil**
>
> *NOTE: Windows Server 2003 or earlier used ntdsutil and was bit of challenge but this was later simplified*
>
> 1. Right Click on Start > Command Prompt (admin)
> 2. Type ntdsutil and enter
> 3. Then metadata cleanup
> 4. Next type `remove selected server <servername>`, replace `<servername>` with DC server to remove
> 5. In warning window click yes to proceed
> 6. Execute quit command twice